# WindowGroup on macOS not creating independent windows

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-windowgroup

Considering the following code

```swift
@main
struct so_tcaMultipleIndepententWindowsOnMacOSApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentViewVanilla()
    }
  }
}

struct ContentViewVanilla: View {
  @State private var id = UUID()

  var body: some View {
    Text(id.uuidString)
  }
}
```

according to Apple's documentation on [`WindowGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup), opening a new window on macOS should open windows that are independent from each other:

> Every window in the group maintains independent state. For example, the system allocates new storage for any State or StateObject variables instantiated by the scene’s view hierarchy for each window that it creates.

So, I'd expect the `UUID` differ in every window I open when running the app–which is not the case. As it is, each new window displays the same `UUID`.

I am on Xcode 15.1 running on macOS 14.2.

What am I missing?

**edit: working with a `StateObject` works as expected, working with `@State` still does not**

When I refactor above code to use a ViewModel that holds the `UUID`, it works as I would expect:

```swift
@main
struct so_tcaMultipleIndepententWindowsOnMacOSApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentViewVanilla()
    }
  }
}

struct ContentViewVanilla: View {
  @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    Text(viewModel.id.uuidString)
  }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  let id = UUID()
}
```

I do understand that there's a difference in using a reference type rather than a value type, but given the information in Apple's documentation (see above), I would hope that I would not need to have to create a separate class here.

The reason I do not want to do this is that I want to use [TCA](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture) which is based on `struct` and not on `class`.

As per Sweeper's comment below, it seems that for Xcode 15.0 and macOS 14.1.1 my first approach is totally creating independent windows, so there is still some hope that this is a bug in Apple's stack that I perhaps should file a feedback for.

Any further thoughts on this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Xcode 15.0 and macOS 14.1.1.

Comment: Interesting... I just opened the same project with Xcode 15.0 on macOS 14.2 with the same result. So there seems to be a change in the OS? Will yet have to wrap it in MVVM and trying with `@StoreObject`, but that should not make a difference, should it? Anyways, thanks for trying and letting me know!

Comment: `@StoreObject` isn't standard SwiftUI is it a typo or a custom property wrapper?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, too much TCA recently, it seems... It is a typo indeed, I meant `@StateObject`...

Comment: Just tried it with `@StateObject` just now–and the behaviour there is just as I would expect it to be... Will see to update the question with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I am not agreeing with the documentation that tells me to expect separate Windows for `@State` (cause it does not for me, even not for the macOS 13 I tried it with, using a virtual machine installation), I found a workaround I can live with right now.

The workaround is wrapping the TCA structs I want to use in an `@ObservableObject` like so:

```swift
import ComposableArchitecture
import SwiftUI

@main
struct so_tcaMultipleIndepententWindowsOnMacOSApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentViewWrapper()
    }
  }
}

struct ContentViewWrapper: View {
  @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel(
    store: Store(
      initialState: AppFeature.State(),
      reducer: {
        AppFeature()
      }
    )
  )

  var body: some View {
    ContentViewTCA(store: viewModel.store)
  }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  let store: StoreOf<AppFeature>

  init(store: StoreOf<AppFeature>) {
    self.store = store
  }
}

struct ContentViewTCA: View {
  @State var store: StoreOf<AppFeature>

  var body: some View {
    AppView(store: store)
  }
}

@Reducer
struct AppFeature {
  @ObservableState
  struct State {
    let id = UUID()
  }

  enum Action {}

  var body: some ReducerOf<Self> {
    Reduce { state, action in
      switch action {}
    }
  }
}

struct AppView: View {
  let store: StoreOf<AppFeature>

  var body: some View {
    Text(store.id.uuidString)
  }
}
```

I will next incorporate this into my real TCA project and see if there are any issues with this approach down the TCA layer–I don't expect any, but than again I was hoping not to need anything like this workaround neither…

Comment: Having implemented this workaround in my real app, I can totally confirm that this approach works.